# Bootstrap: how to use navbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm new on bootstrap and I have a question about it

If I have a code for drop down menu nav bar like this

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Menu <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#menu1">menu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#menu2">menu 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#menu3">menu 3</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

If I click one of menu the link will include like this "www. ...../#menu1"

The question is if I want to make the content appear on the menu that I just click how can I do it?

```
<div class="container">
    <!-- my rough idea is like this-->
    <div id="#menu1"> content from menu 1</div>
    <div id="#menu2"> Content from menu 2</div>
    <div id="#menu3"> Content from menu 2</div>
</div>
```

I've tried many time but it still showing both of data.
I've include from  JavaScript (from bootstrap) like this

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use jQuery to show hide the content. Try this:

1. Add a class="content" to your divs and remove the # from ID

   `<div id="menu1" class="content"> content from menu 1</div>`
2. Add a jQuery event to you nav links

   ```
   $(".dropdown-menu a").on('click',function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); // stops link from loading
      $('.content').hide(); // hides all content divs
      $('#' + $(this).attr('href') ).show(); //get the href and use it find which div to show
   });
   ```

Hope that helps
//Edit